# Check/Uncheck selected treeview items

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview

How can i make it so when a user clicks on the checkbox within the selected items, it changes all the **selected** items in the treeview to match the state of the clicked checkbox? The item that is clicked.

As an example, when i click Jason, it should toggle all the other items selected to also be checked. However what currently happens instead, is Jason becomes the only item selected and checked.

**Before clicking Jason:**

[image]

**Result currently after clicking Jason:**

[image]

**What i would like to happen:**

[image]

```
import sys
import os
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')

        self.ui_items = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.ui_items.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.ui_items.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_items.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.ui_items.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.ui_items.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.ui_items, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.create_model()


    def create_model(self):
        model = self.ui_items.model()
        model.clear()
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Items'])
        self.ui_items.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

        data = {
            'Family 01': ['Amy', 'Kevin'],
            'Family 02': ['Sarah', 'Jason', 'Abby'],
            'Family 03': ['Michelle', 'Mike', 'Scott', 'Allie']
        }

        for k, v in data.items():
            root = []

            # family
            root_node = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            root_node.setData(k, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
            root.append(root_node)

            # children
            for child in v:

                row = []
                row_node = QtGui.QStandardItem()
                row_node.setData(child, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
                row_node.setCheckable(True)
                row.append(row_node)
                root_node.appendRow(row)

            model.appendRow(root)

        self.ui_items.expandAll()
        self.ui_items.resizeColumnToContents(0)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you could explain yourself better, from what I understand assuming that there are some selected items and you press the checkbox that belongs to some of those items then all the other items must have that same status. I am right?

Comment: updated per your request with images. let me know if it does not make sense

Comment: I would consider this poor UI design because it goes against how every other treeview works. The conventional way to do this would be to have a separate button labelled "tick selected" or similar.

Comment: @three_pineapples was not sure if the question asked for someone to complain about my design. Was asking for help about a functionality i wanted, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is connecting to a signal that is emitted when the state of an item changes.

This can be achieved by:

```
model = self.ui_items.model()
model.itemChanged.connect(self.handle_statechange)
```

These lines have to be inserted somewhere after your *setModel()* command. *handle_statechange* is the name of a method that you will have to define:

```
def handle_statechange(self, checked_item):
    state = checked_item.checkState()
    indices = self.ui_items.selectedIndexes()
    for idx in indices:
        item = idx.model().itemFromIndex(idx)
        item.setCheckState(state)
```

**Edit:**
Eyllanesc comments that clicking on a check box deselects all items besides the one with the clicked checkbox. That's the normal behavior, which you can avoid as a user by keeping the "Ctrl"-button clicked. I dont't know if and how you can override this standard behavior as a programmer.

Comment: Have you tried all the cases? For example, in some of my tests I had 3 selected items, and if I click on a checkbox it deselects the other items and when it arrives at the selectedIndexes() slot it only has one item that is the one that was pressed .

Comment: @eyllanesc: I can confirm that you lose the multiple selection, when you click a checkbox (I appended a few lines to my answer). However, I can't reproduce your observation that only one index is returned at selectedIndexes().

Comment: If you want to reproduce the problem you can do the following: select 3 items, let's call it A, B and C and in the first test you have checked in A, in a second test select the same items in the same order and now you have checked in B, and for the third case the same procedure but now you have checked in C.

Comment: I fail to reproduce your problem. `print(len(indices)` always returns the expected value.